# Appending lists / choosing a data structure

Tags: r, list, data-structures, nested-lists

I am evaluating the performance of a simulation that returns a list of performance statistics with every rep. Currently it returns a more complicated version of the following nested list:

```
fakeList = list()
fakeList$group1$stat1 = c("var1" = .3, "var2" = .2)
fakeList$group1$stat2 = c("var1" = .1, "var2" = .3)
fakeList$group2$stat1 = c("var3" = .7)
fakeList$group2$stat3 = c(TRUE)

fakeList
$group1
$group1$stat1
var1 var2 
 0.3  0.2 

$group1$stat2
var1 var2 
 0.1  0.3 


$group2
$group2$stat1
var3 
 0.7 

$group2$stat3
[1] TRUE
```

where `type1` and `type2` are different types of variables in my simulated dataset (e.g., binary and normal), and `stat1`, `stat2`, and `stat3` are the various performance statistics.

I want to add the following new entry to the list as another “row” in the list:

```
newEntry = list()
newEntry$group1$stat1 = c("var1" = .3, "var2" = .4)
newEntry$group1$stat2 = c("var1" = .2, "var2" = .1)
newEntry$group2$stat1 = c("var3" = .9)
newEntry$group2$stat3 = c(FALSE)

newEntry
$group1
$group1$stat1
var1 var2 
 0.3  0.4 

$group1$stat2
var1 var2 
 0.2  0.1 


$group2
$group2$stat1
var3 
 0.9 

$group2$stat3
[1] FALSE
```

I tried `append()` and `c()`, but those just add the new entries to the end of `fakeList`, rather than adding new "rows" in the corresponding lists in `fakeList`.

***Is there a simple, efficient way to do this? Or (I suspect this is the case) should I be using a different data structure entirely?*** My eventual goal is to loop through the simulation, each time adding a new entry to each of the performance statistics. Then I will compute means of each performance statistic across all the simulations, plotting the different groups and stats separately. For that reason, I like the hierarchical organization of the list vs. a dataframe or matrix.

Comment: not enough information given. But my guess is that your code just needs to be changed to add each part of each output into the correct part of the list.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which will `Map` each component of each `list` to each other in turn to give you:

```
Map(function(x,y) Map(rbind,x,y) , fakeList, newEntry)

#$group1
#$group1$stat1
#     var1 var2
#[1,]  0.3  0.2
#[2,]  0.3  0.4
#
#$group1$stat2
#     var1 var2
#[1,]  0.1  0.3
#[2,]  0.2  0.1
#
#
#$group2
#$group2$stat1
#     var3
#[1,]  0.7
#[2,]  0.9
# 
#$group2$stat3
#      [,1]
#[1,]  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE
```